# Is google geocoding service less powerful than google maps search engine?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with google maps geocoding service in order to geocode some addresses and I've realized that certain addresses appear in google maps search engine but they can't be reached with google maps geocoding service.

Eg, the following address is not found by geocoding service but it's found by google maps.

Address: HOTEL REINA CRISTINA ALGECIRAS

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=HOTEL+REINA+CRISTINA+ALGECIRAS&sensor=true (It's found Algeciras not the hotel)

https://maps.google.es/maps?q=HOTEL+REINA+CRISTINA+ALGECIRAS&hl=es&ie=UTF8&sll=36.123247,-5.444669&sspn=0.014525,0.020471&hq=HOTEL+REINA+CRISTINA&hnear=Algeciras,+C%C3%A1diz,+Andaluc%C3%ADa&t=m&z=16&iwloc=A

Could anyone confirm that? Do I need a special license like google maps api for bussiness?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the Places API Autocomplete service: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=HOTEL+REINA+CRISTINA+ALGECIRAS&sensor=false&key=your_key_here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=HOTEL+REINA+CRISTINA+ALGECIRAS&sensor=false&key=your_key_here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API geocoder finds addresses (with a very few very notable exceptions). The Maps geocoder uses other indexes as well, similar to the Places API. If you want to find places of interest without a full postal address, use the Places API.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests) instead.

Comment: The API response is finding the city, not the hotel.